# Multiple Two numbes and compare with another Liquid Tags

Tags: liquid, liquid-template

I am trying to multiple a and b and compare if the product is more than c. How do i do it in liquid tags.

I tried the following but it is not working.

```
{
"a": {% if {{5|times:3}} > 10 %}
10 {% else %} 20
{% endif %}
}
```

Ideally it should print the following right because 5 times 3 is 15 which is greater than 10.

```
{"a": 10}
```

But it prints the following

```
{"a":20}
```